# why the ending symbol dx is also changed into a function of d theta and then multiplied by the integral after substitution?

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

This is a question about trig substitution used in integrals.

Because it is difficult to solve an integral when there is radical in it, we use a trig function of theta to substitute x from the original integral.

The only thing I don't understand is why the ending symbol dx, which indicates that we are integrating the function with respect to the "x" variable, is also changed into a function of d theta and then multiplied by the integral after substitution.

I think after substitution, we can just rewrite dx into d theta.

Comment: if $\theta=f(x)$, then $d\theta=f'(x)dx$

Answer (score 1):

$dx$ and $d\theta$ are not the same thing.  For example, if $x = \sin \theta$, then $\frac{dx}{d\theta} = \cos \theta $ and so $dx = \cos {\theta}  d\theta$.

This is important because if that were not true then just about any substitution would become trivial and integration would be as easy as differentiation.

Comment: " then dx/dθ=cosθ and so dx=cosθdθ." why it feels like u are treating dx/d theta as dx divided by d theta?

Comment: That is what Newton thought he was doing, and it is an effective way of getting the right results even if someone has to pull their hair a bit to make sure it's logically airtight.  I was trained in physics first, so I tend to have methods that look sloppy but work.

Comment: @mirthspritzultyrobscurantism So there are two ways of resolving this. One is simply saying that, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the chain rule, we have $\int_a^b g'(x)f(g(x))\textrm{d}x=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)\textrm{d}u$. This is a borderline trivial and completely rigorous statement. One short-hand for this could be to write "$u=g(x)$ implies $\textrm{d}u=\frac{du}{dx}\textrm{d}x$ since that's sort of how the above look if you think all you're doing is integrating $f$. And this heuristic will always yield correct substitutions.

Comment: *Another* is appealing to measure theory, stating that $\textrm{d}x$ is a *measure* (the ordinary Lesbegue measure) and $\textrm{d}u$ is the measure such that $\textrm{d}u([a,b])=u(b)-u(a)$. In this formulation, $\textrm{d}u=\frac{du}{dx} \textrm{d}x$ is *true* as a statement about measures with densities and can be proven rigorously. One should note, though, that $\frac{du}{dx}$ is a function and not a measure, so although the notation is suggestive, the result isn't literally due to "fractions cancelling out".